# Em um componente do tipo Spinner como é que eu seto ele com um dado que vem de uma webservice?

Tags: android

Estou fazendo dessa forma seria o correto? O problema é que não está funcionando como o esperado segue código:

Aqui  eu pego o dado que vem de uma lista e da outra tela e guardo ela em situacao:

```
         situacao = bundle.getString("situacao");
```

Aqui eu quero setar o componente Spinner com essa opção :

```
        spinnerSituacao.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(situacao));
```

Mas não está funcionda direito o que faço? situacao é um String que pode ser "1" ou "2".

Eu adicionei na lista para ser exibida no Spinner dessa forma:

```
List<String> listaSituacao = new ArrayList<String>();
    listaSituacao.add("Ativo");
    listaSituacao.add("Desativado");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSituacao = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, listaSituacao);
```

E para pegar o respectivo valor dessa forma:

```
 spinnerSituacao.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Situacao = String.valueOf(position + 1);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Qual é a forma esperada??? Ele tá transformando em **1** ou **0**??

Comment: vou editar moço.....

Comment: Que valores estão no Spinner?

Comment: Eu só quero setar um valor já certo que vem de uma webservice e setar no Spinner esse valor na tela de editar

Comment: Tente assim: **spinnerSituacao.setSelection( (Integer.parseInt(situacao)-1 );**

Comment: Funcionou lindo ;)

Comment: Preciso pensar de uma forma mais simplificada mesmo. Espero realmente melhorar bastante isso minha forma de programar...

Comment: Isso você vai pegando com o tempo! é importante prestar atenção e tentar entender o que está acontecendo!!! Debugar a aplicação e colocar uns Log, ajuda bastante! =)

Comment: Obrigada você me ajudou mesmo. =*** Ok.